# How to set few values doing one update for different conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i make the same by doing just one update in SQL?

```
UPDATE TableItem
SET SomeValueN = t1.somevalue
FROM TableItem t
    INNER JOIN TableItem2 t2 ON some keys
    LEFT JOIN TableItem1 t1 ON some keys AND t1.[Month] = month(t2.DateOfCreation)
WHERE t.ItemID = $(some id)

UPDATE TableItem
SET SomeValueN1 = t1.somevalue
FROM TableItem t
    INNER JOIN TableItem2 t2 ON some keys
    LEFT JOIN TableItem1 t1 ON some keys AND t1.[Month] = month(t2.DateOfCreation) + 1
WHERE t.ItemID = $(some id)

UPDATE TableItem
SET SomeValueN2 = t1.somevalue
FROM TableItem t
    INNER JOIN TableItem2 t2 ON some keys
    LEFT JOIN TableItem1 t1 ON some keys AND t1.[Month] = month(t2.DateOfCreation) + 2
WHERE t.ItemID = $(some id)
```

As you can see i want to update different column for different column values. (sorry for english)

Hope that image will help you:

[image]

Comment: Please post table structures for all three tables- TableItem, TableItem1 and TableItem2 in your question. Add a brief clear description of conditions on which you want to update columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using Microsoft SQL MS

Answer (score 1):

You can run sub-queries:

```
UPDATE TableItem t
SET SomeValueN = (SELECT t1.somevalue
       FROM TableItem2 t2
       LEFT JOIN TableItem1 t1 ON 
            some keys AND t1.[Month] = month(t2.DateOfCreation)
       WHERE some keys
       ),
    SomeValueN1 = (SELECT t1.somevalue
       FROM TableItem2 t2 
       LEFT JOIN TableItem1 t1 ON 
             some keys AND t1.[Month] = month(t2.DateOfCreation) + 1
       WHERE some keys
       )
    SomeValueN1 = (SELECT t1.somevalue
       FROM TableItem2 t2 
       LEFT JOIN TableItem1 t1 ON 
             some keys AND t1.[Month] = month(t2.DateOfCreation) + 2
       WHERE some keys
       )
WHERE t.ItemID = $(some id)
```

Depending on SQL engine, you might have to use different alias for each table.

The `some keys` part in `WHERE` clause can contain references to `TableItem t`, for example: `t.item2Id=t2.id`.

To be able to tell more, please share your DB structure and what exactly you expect to achieve.

Comment: thanks, but in that way i still use the same for 3 times (mean joins and where statements)